# Three.js Assigning map to object.children[0] changes whole object's map

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

i am trying to assign map to every object loaded with OBJLoader in one obj file, which is working. The problem is when i am trying to assign other map to only one object from that file and keep the rest with previous map. It changes map for every object.

```
function loadOBJ( geometry, name ) {
loader.load( geometry, function( object ){
    object.traverse( function (child) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.material.map = map;
            child.material.envMap = textureCube;
            child.castShadow = true;
            child.receiveShadow = true;
            child.material.needsUpdate = true;
        }
    });

    object.children[0].material.map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/ground.jpg");
    object.name = name;
    scene.add( object );
    console.log(object.name);
}); }
```

Even when i run traverse only for object.children[0] and assign the map there, the result is same. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change a property of a material, that change will appear on all renderable objects that share that material. That is likely what is happening in your case.

Use this pattern:

```
newMaterial = object.children[ 0 ].material.clone();

newMaterial.map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/ground.jpg" );

object.children[ 0 ].material = newMaterial;
```

three.js r.75

Comment: Thanks, working nice. I just thought that my object has its own material and not that i have material and assign it to object.